# Почему нельзя использовать константы для match?

Tags: python

Я просматривал ответ на [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525257/capture-makes-remaining-patterns-unreachable), а потом [узнал](https://www.wrighters.io/intro-to-python-match-statement/#:%7E:text=It%E2%80%99s%20not%20intended%20to%20be%20used%20strictly%20as%20a%20switch), что `match` не такой же, как обычный switch.

Пример:

```py
a = 2
b = 2

match a:
    case 1: print("1!")
    case b: print("2!") #<-- так нельзя.
    case 3: print("3!")
```

А так же там везде советовали использовать "точечную запись" для решения этой проблемы. Даже показали как оно [там](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#capture-patterns) устроено.

Окей, это конечно же всё круто, только похоже на обычное "низкоуровневое" объяснение, типа "вот так сделай и не парь себе мозги".

Но где я могу получить более высокоуровневое объяснение?

В чём концептуальная идея невозможности использования констант для match в python?

Comment: `case b:` определяет новую переменную, равную  значению  выражения из `match `. Так сделано.

Comment: хрень какую-то придумали)  сделали бы 2 отдельных оператора "switch" и "match"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

match реализует не сравнение, а т.н. [Сопоставление с образцом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%BC) - очень распространенный прием в функциональном программировании.

Значение в match сопоставляется с одним или несколькими образцами, состоящими из литералов, имен классов и переменных. Тело первого case с совпадающим образцом выполняется, остальные игнорируются. При этом переменным из образца присваиваются значения, которым они соответствуют.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

match lst:
    case [x, _, y, _, *rest]:
        print(x, y, rest) # 1 3 [5, 6]
```

Переменные `x`, `y`, `rest` *создаются* в этом месте. Сравнения с ними не производится.

В некотором смысле эта конструкция похожа на обычное множественное присваивание

```py
[x, _, y, _, *rest] = lst
print(x, y, rest) # 1 3 [5, 6]
```

За некоторыми исключениями:

- В случае несоответствия выражения образцу не произойдет ошибки

```py
match [1]:
    case x, y, z: # эта ветка проигнорируется
        pass

x, y, z = [1] # ошибка
```

- Паттерны вроде `(x,y,z)`, `[x,y,z]`, `x,y,z` (это синонимы), как в примере выше, нельзя сопоставлять произвольным итерируемым объектам, только последовательностям (реализующим Sequence), кроме строк (и bytes).

```py
match 'test':
    case x, y, *z: # здесь не будет совпадения
        print(x, y, z)

match map(int, '1234'):
    case x, y, *z: # здесь тоже
        print(x, y, z)

x, y, *z = 'test'
print(x, y, z) # t e ['s', 't']

x, y, *z = map(int, '1234')
print(x, y, z) # 1 2 [3, 4]
```

- `_` является частью синтаксиса, а не именем переменной, и эта часть выражения по настоящему игнорируется, ни чему не присваивается, и время на ее копирование не тратится.

```py
match range(1000000):
    case x, *_, y: # здесь время потратится только на извлечение двух элементов
        print(x, y) # 0 999999
        # попытка вывести _ приведет к ошибке отсутствия соответствующей переменной

x, *_, y = range(1000000) # здесь - также на копирование последовательности в список `_`
print(_) # [1..99998]
```

Т.к. просто имени переменной удачно сопоставляется любое выражение, в вашем случае

```py
match a:
    case b:
        # здесь b при сваеивается значение a
```

это то же самое, что

```py
b = a
```

Но если вам действительно нужно сравнение

```py
a = 2
b = 2

match a:
    case 1: print("1!")
    case x if x == b: print("2!") #<-- так можно.
    case 3: print("3!")
```

Конечно, этим возможности сопоставления не ограничиваются. Особенно удобно использовать их с датаклассами, или другими классами реализующими соответствующий функционал

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Data:
    x: bool
    y: str

for rec in [Data(True, 'a'), Data(True, 'B'), Data(False, 'b')]:
    match rec:
        case Data(True, y) if y.islower():
            print(y)
        case _:
            print(rec, "не совпадает")
```

```
a
Data(x=True, y='B') не совпадает
Data(x=False, y='b') не совпадает
```

Answer (score 4):

как всегда в питоне немного перемудрили. один и тот же матч делает и сравнение и присваивание.

присваивание он делает, если положить в match список, а в case подбирается количество переменных для распаковки.

в вашем случае не понятно присваивание должно делаться или сравнение.